# Multiple HttpGet actions in a Web Api Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller with the following actions defined:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) {}

[ActionName("Orders")]
public IHttpActionResult GetOrders(int id) {}
```

And my routing is as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerWithId",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerWithAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { action = "Get" },
    constraints: null
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerWithIdAndAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" 
};
```

I would like to call the GetOrders as follows:

```
/api/Customers/1/Orders
```

However, I get the exception:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request: Get

What is the correct routing in this case?

Comment: you should specify the routeTemplate as `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}`, epecially when `id` is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because both of your actions are being matched with the first route template `ControllerWithId`! This basically has happened because you mixed  **verb-based routing** (which is default routing mechanism in Web-Api) and **action based routing**. You should stick to one of them! Based on your controller and actions you can combine the first and second route templates like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "ControllerWithAction",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Get" },
constraints: null);
```

This will cover your scenario but if you want to address more complicated scenarios take a look at [Web API: Mixing Traditional & Verb-Based Routing](http://blog.appliedis.com/2013/03/25/web-api-mixing-traditional-verb-based-routing/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'Route' decorator rather than the 'ActionName' decorator.

```
[Route("{id:int}/orders")]
```